# Can't figure out python query.

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to post this query into my database. The problem is I'm querying from a csv that has placeholders: I can't seem to get:   `Time_Date_Uploaded` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL filled with the current time. here is my code below:

```
    cursor = mydb.cursor() # declare object
now = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') #want to send the current time to the database.
cr.next() # need to skip first line of csv
for row in cr:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO loans2(LoanId, NoteId, OrderId, OutstandingPrincipal, AccruedInterest, Status, AskPrice, Markup_Discount, YTM, DaysSinceLastPayment, CreditScoreTrend, FICO_End_Range, Date_Time_Listed, NeverLate, Loan_Class, Loan_Maturity, Original_Note_Amount, Interest_Rate, Remaining_Payments, Principal_plus_Interest, Time_Date_Uploaded) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s")' % tuple(row))
# #close the connection to the database.
    mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see how many items the `row` has. I assume it's a list. If it has the number of items equal to fields in your database minus one, you should be able to simply do `row.append(now)` before `cursor.execute` and it would work. If it has the exact same number of items as you have fields, you have to throw something out and replace it with `now`, for example do this `row[-1] = now` before `cursor.execute`. If you don't know how many fields your `row` list has, do a `print len(row)` as a debug. Either way you need to get the `now` value into the `row` list.

p.s. I'm assuming you are using python 2 from the print statement, that's why I use the same print semantic, if I'm wrong and you're on python 3, use `print()` instead of course :)

Comment: thanks man! works perfectly. Unfort can't upvote says I need 15 reputation or something.